# CEF Sharp causing an Object Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

While I understand what an object disposed exception is, I don't quite know why it is occurring immediately after the object is instantiated. Below is my code:

```
var cookiemanager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
cookiemanager.SetCookieAsync(Domain, Cookie);
```

The error is occurring on the second line when I attempt to call the SetCookieAsync function stating:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in CefSharp.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Any help on why the object was disposed or what I can do to remedy this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need a "new" as in cookiemanager = new Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager()?

Comment: I thought that at first, however, adding "new" causes Visual Studio to redline that statement with the following error: The type name GetGlobalCookieManager does not exist in the type Cef

Comment: What version are you using? At what point are you calling `GetGlobalCookieManager`?

Comment: I am so sorry for the delay, I am using version 45.0. `GetGlobalCookieManager` is being called in the program in order to work with cookies (of course). I have declared a Cef Cookie that I am trying to place in the following `SetCookieAsync` call. I hope that helps explain my issue a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tinkering I decided to look at the provided Cef examples where I found the following snippet:

```
Cef.OnContextInitialized = delegate
{
    var cookiemanager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
    cookiemanager.SetCookieAsync(Domain, Cookie);
};
```

Making this changed seemed to work!